# Assigning values to array using eval in Python?

Tags: python, arrays, eval

I have a whole series of arrays with similar names mcmcdata.rho0, mcmcdata.rho1, ... and I want to be able to loop through them while updating their values. I can't figure out how this might be done or even what such a thing might be called.

I read my data in from file like this:

```
names1='l b rho0 rho1 rho2 rho3 rho4 rho5 rho6 rho7 rho8 rho9 rho10 rho11 rho12 rho13 rho14 rho15 rho16 rho17 rho18 rho19 rho20 rho21 rho22 rho23'.split()
mcmcdata=np.genfromtxt(filename,names=names1,dtype=None).view(np.recarray)
```

and I want to update the "rho" arrays later on after I do some calculations.

```
for jj in range(dbins):

    mcmc_x, mcmc_y, mcmc_z = wf.lbd_to_xyz(mcmcdata.l,mcmcdata.b,d[jj],R_sun)

    rho, thindisk, thickdisk, halo = wf.total_density_fithRthinhRthickhzthinhzthickhrfRiA( mcmc_x, mcmc_y, mcmc_z, R_sun,params)

    eval("mcmcdata."+names1[2+jj]) = copy.deepcopy(rho)
    eval("mcmcthin."+names1[2+jj]) = copy.deepcopy(thindisk)
    eval("mcmcthick."+names1[2+jj]) = copy.deepcopy(thickdisk)
    eval("mcmchalo."+names1[2+jj]) = copy.deepcopy(halo)
```

But the eval command is giving an error:

```
File "<ipython-input-133-30322c5e633d>", line 13
    eval("mcmcdata."+names1[2+jj]) = copy.deepcopy(rho)
SyntaxError: can't assign to function call
```

How can I loop through my existing arrays and update their values?
or
How can identify the arrays by name so I can update them?

Comment: IMHO what you're doing looks weird. You should probably put your arrays to other array (we're talking about lists right?) if you want to iterate over them. This looks like [XY problem](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem) to me.

Comment: Don't use dynamic variable names, use a list.

Comment: It seems like you could use [`setattr`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#setattr): `setattr(mcmcdata, names1[2+jj], copy.deepcopy(rho))`. I'm not familiar with Numpy, though, so maybe that doesn't work on Numpy views.

Comment: Why in the world do you think `eval` is the right tool for this job?

Comment: This is definitely some kind of XY problem and you should write your actual problem description. This question reads like you're asking, "How do I hammer nails in with a shoe?"

Comment: well I'm defining the name of the array I want to use as a text string and I want then use that to reference back to the real thing, but I'm a bit confused about how to do that. (as you can tell).

Comment: @Two-BitAlchemist I honestly don't know how to describe the problem which is part of the reason I'm having trouble finding a solution. I think it's something like how do I use a string to point back to an array of the same name? perhaps that's a better title.

Comment: @RobKennedy I think that is working, thanks so much.

Answer (score 1):

The `eval` command doesn't work the way you seem to think it does. You appear to be using it like a text-replacement macro, hoping that Python will read the given string and then pretend you wrote that text in the original source code. Instead, it receives a string, and then it *executes* that code. You're giving it an expression that refers to an attribute of an object, which is fine, but the result of evaluating that expression does not yield a thing you can assign to. It yields the *value* of that attribute.

Although Python provides `eval`, it also provides many other things that often obviate the need for `eval`. In the case of your code, Python provides [`setattr`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#setattr). You give it an object, the name of an attribute on that object, and a value, and it assigns that object's attribute to refer to the given value.

```
setattr(mcmcdata, names1[2+jj], copy.deepcopy(rho))
```

It *might* make the code more readable to get rid of the `names1` portion, too. I might write the code like this:

```
setattr(mcmcdata, 'rho' + str(jj), copy.deepcopy(rho))
```

That way, it's clear that I'm assigning the rho-related attributes of the object without having to go look at what's held in the `names1` list; the name *names1* doesn't offer much information about what's in it.

Comment: Can you think of a better way to word the question that might make it more useful for other people?